# Typo3 glossary with support for categories

Tags: gratis

I need a recommendation on a *TYPO3 extension* compatible with **version 6.1.2**, that can be used to maintain a glossary. Since it is intended to hold concepts of various domains, it should provide means to

- organize terms by **categories**,
- allow to **filter** the view accordingly,
- **sort** alpha-numerically *within* a category or *over all* categories.

Automatic highlighting / tagging of terms in the content **is not a must**, 
but it would be nice to have it applied only on the first occurrence of a word on a page.